# how to login MEGA with 2fa in C#

Tags: c#

I am using `MegaApiClient` in my C# project. I want to upload file from my computer to my mega cloud. I am using two factor authentication in my mega account. When I turn off `2fa`, I can login and upload file.However, I want to login with `2fa` and upload file. My codes are here. Thanks.

```
public async Task UploadToMega(string megaFolderName, string megaFolderID, string filePathOnComputer)
{
    //Start Mega Cient
    var myMegaClient = new MegaApiClient();

    //Login To Mega
    myMegaClient.Login("email@gmail.com", "password");

    //Get All (File & Folders) in Mega Account
    IEnumerable<INode> nodes = myMegaClient.GetNodes();

    //Creat List Of All Folders In Mega Account
    List<INode> megaFolders = nodes.Where(n => n.Type == NodeType.Directory).ToList();

    //Choose Exist Folder In Mega Account By Name & Id
    INode myFolderOnMega = megaFolders.Where(folder => folder.Name == megaFolderName && folder.Id == megaFolderID).FirstOrDefault();


    //Upload The File
    //Normal Upload
    //INode myFile = myMegaClient.UploadFile(filePathOnComputer, myFolderOnMega);

    var progress = new Progress<double>();
    progress.ProgressChanged += (s, progressValue) =>
    {
        //Update the UI (or whatever) with the progressValue 
        progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(progressValue);
    };

    if (uploadCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        uploadCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        uploadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    // Upload With progress bar
    INode myFile = await myMegaClient.UploadFileAsync(filePathOnComputer, myFolderOnMega, progress, uploadCancellationTokenSource.Token);

    //Get Download Link
    Uri downloadLink = myMegaClient.GetDownloadLink(myFile);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking

Comment: I want to login mega in C# WinForm project without turn off 2fa on my mega account.

Answer (score 0):

Based on their [Github](https://github.com/gpailler/MegaApiClient) it looks like they currently do not support 2FA using `MegaApiClient`: https://github.com/gpailler/MegaApiClient/issues/140